# Power BI Report Server Refresh Issue -- " he timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding "

Tags: sql, powerbi

Greeting

I have issue in Power BI Report Server, when i refresh the dashboard from portal, the error in below

[image]

I search many time but no have any solution for Power BI Report Server.

Comment: What are you querying? A sql database? If it is the query has timed out, suggesting that it is long running. Does it work in PBI Desktop and not the service?